# When encoding a video, is there a way to know the resulting file size in advance?

Tags: video-conversion, video-editing, video-capture, microsoft-expression

Is there a way to know how large your resulting file size will be before your video is finished encoding?

BTW: I am using [Microsoft Expression Encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Expression_Encoder).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is. To bring up the tool that is built into Expression, go to Window and click on "Summary" to check it.

You can also estimate it yourself using one of the formulae you can read about here: http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/299571-How-to-calculate-size-of-video-file-after-encoding

[image]

Comment: In general, I think you can know by multiply the bitrate by the length of the video in *seconds*. Jeremy, was this sample video ~255 seconds by chance?

Comment: @MDMoore313 But then you'd need to factor in audio streams and the container overhead as well.

Comment: @slhck overhead yes, but why wouldn't that codec take audio into account, I mean what's a video without audio?